# Bootstrap set popover content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to find a way to dynamically modify the content of a bootstrap popover using Javascript, however the method i have come across so far have not worked :

```
<!--object with the popover-->
<input id="popoverlist" type="text" name="poplist" placeholder="Enter data"  data-html="true" data-content="" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="pop list" >

$('#popoverlist').popover({
                offset: 10,
                trigger: 'manual',
                animate: false,
                html: true,
                placement: 'left',
                template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

            }).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault() ;
            }).mouseenter(function(e) {
                $(this).popover('show');
            });
```

The methods i have been trying to use to set the html content are :

```
$('#popoverlist').data('bs.popover').html("<p>New content</p>");
//and using the inner HTML
document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML = '<p>New content</p>';
```

However neither of those methods change the html data content. I would appreciate any help on this to point me in the correct direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second idea works, but you need to invoke it *after* the popover-content has been created.

The popover isn't created until the first time it is shown, and is recreated after each call to `show`. Thus, you need to change the content after `$(this).popover('show');`.

I've included a snippet showing this in action:

```js
$('#popoverlist').popover({
  offset: 10,
  trigger: 'manual',
  animate: false,
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

}).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() ;
}).mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).popover('show');
  
  // dynamically change content after show
  document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML = '<p>New content</p>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="popoverlist" type="text" name="poplist" placeholder="Enter data"  data-html="true" data-content="" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="pop list" >
```

Comment: You were right, once i swapped position the content did change, thanks :)